# How to pass intent data when starting app via adb

Tags: android, adb

I am able to start an activity with adb as below

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

How do I add intent data to this command so that I can retrieve it from the started activity?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is some sample commands :

```
# specifying the action and data uri
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "http://developer.android.com"

# specifying the action, mime type and an extra string 
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.SEND" --es "android.intent.extra.TEXT" "Hello World" -t "text/plain"

# specifying an explicit component name 
adb shell am start -n "com.example.application/.MainActivity"
```

---

The application [With intent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zachklipp.intentsendertool) allow to send intent.

I found those informations there : http://www.xgouchet.fr/android/index.php?article42/launch-intents-using-adb